# Inflating Android OptionsMenu based on Login Status

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

Here is my Code:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        MenuItem Login = menu.findItem(R.id.Login);
        MenuItem Logout = menu.findItem(R.id.Logout);
        MenuItem About = menu.findItem(R.id.About);
        MenuItem Profile = menu.findItem(R.id.Profile);

        // set the menu options depending on login status
        if (LoggedStatus == true) {
            // show the log out option
            Logout.setVisible(true);
            Login.setVisible(false);

            Profile.setVisible(true);
            About.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            // show the log in option
            Logout.setVisible(false);
            Login.setVisible(true);

            Profile.setVisible(false); // hide
            About.setVisible(true);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.Login:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        case R.id.Logout:

            return true;
        case R.id.Profile:

            return true;
        case R.id.About:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I am getting `Null pointer exception` on each of the four MenuItem's.
I simply want one menu for login, and one for logout.

EDIT:  This is an app utilizing the Action Bar, Overflow menu and Android 4.0+
Also, More Code.  **Here is menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:title="Login"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Logout"
        android:title="Logout"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Profile"
        android:title="My Profile"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/About"
        android:title="About"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: For each of the four MenuItem's -- it doesn't matter how I order it.

Comment: Normally i can set visibility of `MenuItem` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Try to move there

Comment: @Yul  That was it!  Go ahead and add the answer and I will mark correct.

Comment: Hey bonus points; I've got this working.  But how do you change the menu on the existing activity without refreshing the whole thing?  Right now, I have to go to another activity and come back to actually see the menu updated.

Comment: I do not see an option for this in the menu class. You could try removing the menu items and re adding them. Seems like something you would want to do once, not every menu interaction though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set visibility of `MenuItem` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Try to move there.

**About bonus**: . In [DOC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) they told `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called **everytime** you press menu . I tested with one button change `boolean` param `onClick` to show/hide `MenuItem` and everything's fine